# What's the difference between 许多 and 很多？

Tags: grammar, usage, difference

What's the difference between 许多 and 很多？

I have learned that 许多 can't be used as predicate yet in this sentence it seems to have a predicative function

> 他觉得妻子虽然老了许多 但仍很美丽

Comment: Why do you think it has a predicative funtion? I think it's just an adverb for descripting the level of `老了`.

Answer (score 0):

it's almost the same. both means a lot, very much..

Answer (score 0):

许多 usally in written, and 很多 usually in speech.